# sql iterate two parent child table with relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Suppose I have two tables that have parent-child relation inside.

Profile:

[image]

Report:

[image]

ProfileReport:

[image]

and UserProfile:

[image]

My scenario is to find user's profile list first, then find report tree of user's profiles. 
What I tried so far is:

```
;WITH ProfileReports AS 
(
 SELECT  pr.ReportId as ReportId
FROM     ProfileReport AS pr
         INNER JOIN [Profile] AS p ON pr.ProfileId = p.Id AND p.[Status] = 1
         INNER JOIN UserProfile AS up ON p.Id = up.ProfileId AND up.[Status] = 1 
         INNER JOIN [User] AS u ON up.UserId = u.Id AND u.Id = 1 and u.[Status] = 1  
),
Parents
AS       (SELECT r.Id,
                 r.ParentId,
                 r.Name
          FROM   Report AS r
          WHERE   r.Id in (select ReportId from ProfileReports ) AND r.[Status] = 1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT p.Id,
                 p.ParentId,
                 p.Name
          FROM   Report AS p INNER JOIN Parents AS rl ON p.Id = rl.ParentId
          WHERE  p.[Status] = 1)
,Childs 
AS 
(
SELECT r.Id,
       r.ParentId,
       r.Name
          FROM   Report AS r
          WHERE   r.Id in (select ReportId from ProfileReports) AND r.[Status] = 1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT p.Id,
                 p.ParentId,
                 p.Name
          FROM   Report AS p INNER JOIN Childs AS rl ON p.ParentId = rl.Id
          WHERE  p.[Status] = 1

 )

 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
 SELECT  * FROM Parents
     UNION ALL
 SELECT  * FROM Childs) t
```

But I couldnt get report tree correct. Is there any way to achieve finding profile tree and then finding report tree that's corresponding to profile tree user has?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s I use sql-server

Comment: @MehmetInce - Add sample data and expected result as text in table format